# Change data type column from string to date with custom format

Tags: scala, date, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a DF with a string column called "data" in the format 02/09/2019 (dd/MM/yyyy). I want to change the data type of the column from STRING to DATE, maintaining the same format. I'm using Spark 2.1.0.

I've tried the statement:

```
df.select(to_date( unix_timestamp($"data", "dd/MM/yyyy").cast("timestamp")))
```

It converts the column from STRING to DATE but in yyyy-MM-dd format:

```
+----------+
|      data|
+----------+
|2003-07-22|
|2003-08-01|
+----------+
```

Using date_format function, I obtain the right format but wrong data type (again STRING):

```
df.select(date_format(to_date( unix_timestamp($"data", "dd/MM/yyyy").cast("timestamp")), "dd/MM/yyyy") as "data").printSchema()
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**`Date`** datatype expects the format as **`yyyy-MM-dd`**.

If we have format as `dd/MM/yyyy` and we cannot cast as `date` datatype `(casting will result null value)`.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show() //sample data

+----------+
|      data|
+----------+
|22/07/2003|
|01/08/2003|
+----------+
```

---

```
df.selectExpr("date(data)").show() //casting to date type

+----+
|data|
+----+
|null|
|null|
+----+
```

> ***`How to cast to Datetype?`***

```
df.select(to_date(unix_timestamp($"data","dd/MM/yyyy").cast("timestamp")).alias("da")).show()
```

(or)

```
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"data","dd/MM/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd").cast("date").alias("da")).show()

+----------+
|        da|
+----------+
|2003-07-22|
|2003-08-01|
+----------+
```

---

> **`printSchema:`**

```
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"data","dd/MM/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd").cast("date").alias("dd")).printSchema
root
 |-- dd: date (nullable = true)
```